# the problem with Blend tree, how to fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

error : BlendTree "Blend Tree" in state "Blend Tree" in Controller "Money" uses parameter "Blend" which does not exist.
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_RestoreLastOpenedScenes ()

as far as I understand, the problem is in the Blend tree, but I've never used it, so I don't understand how to fix it

Comment: Did you try adding a parameter called Blend?

Comment: yes . in general , as I understand it , I should have a Blend tree in the animator , but it 's not there , most likely I deleted it

Comment: well as I said put it back it was in use. You may have deleted the parameter but not what used it

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in Unity: If you delete a Blend Tree in the Animator, it still remains in the file and may try to access the "Blend" parameter even though this was deleted as well (and got properly deleted from the file).

**A solution is to open the file with a text editor and delete the Blend Tree corpse from it.**

You can find it by searching for "BlendTree". If multiple are found and you don't know which of them is unused, search for the number in the line above, e.g. search for `2629503023377028427` if the two lines in the file look like this:

```
--- !u!206 &2629503023377028427
BlendTree:
```

If that number shows up e.g. in the `m_Motion` field of an `AnimatorState`, then you know it is used by that state. Otherwise you found the leftover BlendTree and can delete it.